# Any way to make PHP var_dump display deeper nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I am working on a script that takes uploaded INI files and converts them to a database.  The INI files are quite poorly written and created loops inside themselves.
I am first converting the INIs into arrays, nested in the way that they will be inserted into database tables.
But this means I am having 4 levels and deeper of arrays. More than var_dump will show.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array);
echo "</pre>";
```

works, but it's not nicely formatted, and it's cumbersome, so I am hoping var_dump can be modified somehow to be allowed to go deeper.
Is there such an option?

Thanks

-Edit, found the answer, it was a duplicate.
Posting as a clarification to other searchers.
Open your php.ini, 
find the section called `[xdebug]`
add this to the end of the section `xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1`

Comment: Thanks, edited my question with the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind if you have `xdebug` installed it will limit the `var_dump()` output of array elements and object properties to 3 levels deep.

To change the default, edit your `xdebug.ini` file and add the folllowing line:

```
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=n
```

where `n` is your max level.

More information here:
http://www.xdebug.org/docs/display

Answer (score 4):

Or simply add this at your script:

```rb
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 99);
```